# javascript, how to implement an index page function to execute a seperate page of .js functions

Tags: javascript, forms, function, calendar

I've created two functions which perform these tasks:

```
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    /* get the month from current Date */

    /* Set the imgsource variable to be the defaultLogo
            image */

    /* If month is 12, 1, or 2, set variable imgsource to
              winterLogo or to the defaultLogo if not one of those 
              three months */

    /* If month is 3, 4, or 5, set imgsource to springLogo 
              or to the defaultLogo if not one of those three
              months */

    /* If month is 6, 7, or 8, set imgsource to summerLogo 
              or to the defaultLogo if not one of those three
              months */

    /* If month is 10, 11, or 12, set imgsource to fallLogo 
              or to the defaultLogo if not one of those three
              months */

    /* Return the imagesource variable to set the myBanner 
              imgSrc attribute to that image*/
}

function calcDaysToSale(currentDate) {
    /* create a Date object for the 15th of the 
              current month */
    /* compute difference in days between currentDate
              And the 15th */
    /* if the difference is positive return that value
              Else return message that the sale is over for this 
              month */
}
```

However! I'm meant to create a third function which can reside in the header of an index page that can subsequently execute the functions and therein lies the problem- I can't figure it out.

I've check my work using the 'alert();' function and that shows that the operation of the two I've created is sound but I just can't pin down how to get their act together so to speak.

The page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var curdate = new Date()
alert(curdate);

function displayBanner(currenttDate) {
    var munf = currenttDate.getMonth();

    switch (munf) {
    case 9:
    case 8:
    case 10:
        imageSrc = 'fallLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 11:
    case 0:
    case 1:
        imageSrc = 'winterLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        imageSrc = 'springLogo.gif';
        break;
    case 7:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        imageSrc = 'summerLogo.gif';
        break;
    default:
        imageSrc = 'defaultLogo.gif';
    }

    return imageSrc;
}


function calcDaysToSale(currentDate) {

    var saleMessage;
    var mday = currentDate.getDate()

    if (currentDate < 15) {
        var lef = (15 - currentDate);
        //alert("There are " + lef + " days until the Sale.");
        saleMessage = lef;
    } else if (currentDate == 15) {
        //alert("The Sale is today!");
        saleMessage = "Zero, it's Today!";
    } else {
        //alert("The Sale for this month has ended.");
        saleMessage = "The Sale for this month has ended.";
    }

    return saleMessage;
}

alert(calcDaysToSale(curdate));
alert(displayBanner(curdate));

function pageSetup() {
}



 </script>

</head>

<body  class="oneColLiqCtrHdr">

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<p><img name="myBanner" id="myBanner" src="" alt="Carol's Flowers" />

  <!-- end #header -->
</p>
<div id="links"><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">General Arrangements</a> | 
<a href="#">Seasonal Designs</a> | <a href="#">Custom Orders</a> | 
<a href="#">Location</a></div>

</div>
<div id="mainContent">
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
   <td width="201"><h1><img src="Flowers.JPG" alt="Random Flowers" width="200"   height="255" /></h1></td>
   <td width="687">
<p>Here at Carol's Flowers, we believe that there is a perfect floral arrangment for  every occasion! Take a look around and see if there is anything you like. If we don't  already have it, then we will create it for you!</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- end #mainContent --></div>
<div id="footer">
<p> <form name="sale" id="sale">
  Days Until Mid Month Madness Sale : 
  <input type="text" name="saleMessage" id="saleMessage" /></form></p>


<!-- end #footer --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But as I said I'm meant to cut those first two functions out, throw them into that seperate 'flowers.js' page and run everything with the pagesetup() function.

The goal of those two functions is to set the image source for a banner on the one hand and on the other to display in the bottom form the number of days left until the 'sale' which takes place on the 15th of the month, or if the 15th has passed, to let the user know that info.

Comment: ECMAScript/Javscript is not the same thing as Java.

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to achieve in just three lines ? keep it simple.. if you do i'll help

Comment: what, exactly, is happening if you do put those functions in the other js file? Do you get an error?

Comment: Your problem is a little ill-defined, but I'll admit you seem to be aware of that; I at least understand that the page doesn't appear to be doing what you hope it to. At the least, are you aware of the debugging tools most modern browsers give you? You'll still need to test in older browsers, but if you open, say, Google Chrome and press F12, then click the Script tab, you can actually set breakpoints to give yourself a lot of better information than just using "alert()" in various places. It also has a Console that will report errors like "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not very clear. Let me take a shot at it. So, you moved the two functions to a new js file "flowers.js". Included flowers.js on this page and now tried calling the two functions from the pageSetup method which exists on this page. Is that what you tried? Did it not work?

If not, then you need to make sure that "flowers.js" has finished loading before you can call it's functions. one way to check if this is causing the issue is to change the code to call pageSetup only after the page has finished loading.

```
<body onload="pageSetup();">
```

Let me know if your problem is something completely different. :)

EDIT:
for setting the image source in run-time using javascript, you can do the following..

```
<img id="my_image_id" src="Flowers.JPG" alt="Random Flowers" width="200"   height="255" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("my_image_id").src=displayBanner(10);
    }
</script>
```

PS:
rename displayBanner to get_image_source or something..

Comment: Although your question is not very clear. Let me take a shot at it. 


So, you moved the two functions to a new js file "flowers.js". Included flowers.js on this page and now tried calling the two functions from the pageSetup method which exists on this page. Is that what you tried? Did it not work?

Comment: Although your question is not very clear. Let me take a shot at it. So, you moved the two functions to a new js file "flowers.js". Included flowers.js on this page and now tried calling the two functions from the pageSetup method which exists on this page.

Hi all ^ that is exactly right.

I have the two functions, and they seem to work, but I want to get them out of the header of my index page and transport them to a seperate flowers.js page and subsequently utilize them by means of a third funtion (to be housed in the original index page) called pagesetup().

Comment: One other thing I'm not quite sure how to do is how exactly to set the image source from that function-> is it necessary to go down into the code until after the image has therein executed and then following that add a <script> portion to perform the image set?

The text box is the same thing, I don't quite know hot to write the result of the "Sale" function to that text box. 

Thank you for your patience in reading this and trying to help me figure this out. I apologize for my laughable ignorance. I sincerely appreciate everyones consideration.